# How to find similar words in two strings in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a string containing words that i need to match like the one below, it is constant and the other string that can be changed may contain words from this string 's'.

```
string s = "run fun play game do work click type";

string g = "he will be running. He is playing a game by clicking the mouse";
```

I want to be be able to match these words and make them bold in a windows form application text box. Like **run** and **Running** match so running will be turned bold and so on. :-/ any ideas??

Comment: Are you searching for Run or are you comparing words in both strings to see if anything matches?

Comment: It's a classic Levenshtein distance problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance Pseudo code included in the article.

Comment: Not really. In his example:

Run -> Running
would have a large distance (add 4)
However Fun -> Run
Would have less distance. And they're not related.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify it, can you review it please

Comment: F(un) = R(un) at least according to the question asked.  But more importantly, your stems approach fails on brown and brownian...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do is use a stemmer (such as the Porter stemmer), split the strings using a split(' ') and go through each. Compare the stemmed version of both words and then bold the ones which match.

```
foreach (string t1 in term1.split(' '){

foreach (string t2 in term2.split(' '){

if (Stemmer.Stem(t1).equals(Stemmer.Stem(t2)){

//do whatever here

}

}    

    }
```

On the porter stemmer including source code:

http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/